# Loading Firefox profiles on Selenium causes Firefox to start a minute late. How do I eliminate this delay?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, automation, geckodriver

The task I'm required to complete requires me to use Firefox profiles. However, if I use profiles, it takes around 50 seconds for Firefox to startup. Without profiles it takes literally no delay.

I'm looking to eliminate this delay completely since the program itself takes only 25 seconds to run. Any suggestions? My OS is MacOS 10.13.3.

I've included the code for the constructor below.

```
    public test() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", geckodriver_path);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", firefox_path);
        ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("test2");
        options.setProfile(myprofile); 
        webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

Comment: try Chrome it more responsive and use less disk space in `tmp` folder

Comment: Worked on downsizing the profile. Brought it down from 50MB to 8MB by removing unessential files. However it still takes about 10 seconds for Firefox to start-up. If this was eliminated as well, then it'd be ideal.

Comment: The profile uses Google log-in cookies. That itself takes up about 6MB. If that was deleted, then it'd defeat the very purpose of the program since it requires me to be logged in via Google.

Comment: Would use Chrome, however I'd have to code the entire thing from scratch, that's what I'm thinking about.

Comment: I think not entire code, only before `webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(options);` but if you comfortable with firefox let continue using it.

Comment: Thank you. Recoded it for the ChromeDriver and it got sorted. Works like a charm. :) Wish there was an optimal solution for this in Firefox though. Couldn't find anything online.

Comment: Create a custom profile that contains nothing but what is required for your script. That should make it load faster.

Comment: for optimal solution you need to patch geckodriver to stop creating temporary profile `rust_mozprofile`